# How to swap out a view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to piece together a very simple iPhone application with two visible views.

I have a RootViewController, a View1Controller and a View2Controller. In my RootViewController I have a button that switches one view to the other. That looks like...

```
- (IBAction)flipView:(id)sender
{
    if (self.view2Controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        if (self.view2Controller == nil)
        {
            self.view2Controller = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2Controller" bundle:nil];
        }
        [view1Controller.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.view2Controller.view atIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.view1Controller == nil)
        {
            self.view1Controller = [[View1Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1Controller" bundle:nil];
        }
        [view2Controller.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.view1Controller.view atIndex:0];

    }
}
```

That works great. The button in the RootView hits this method and swaps the views out no problem.

I'm trying to hook up a button in both View1Controller and View2Controller that links to the other and I'm having problems.

I've managed to get as far as...

```
- (IBAction)swap:(id)sender {

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    // This is where I get stuck
}
```

I've tried looking around but I can't work out what to do in this situation. How do I load a new view in my superclass' view? Is that even what I want to do here? Am I dropping the code in the right place?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add directly the one view controller's view to the other's. Try doing it using modal view controllers:

In View1Controller.m:

```
- (void) flipView:(id)sender
{
    View2Controller *vc2 = [[View2Controller alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
    [vc2 release];
}
```

In View2Controller.m:

```
- (void) swap:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```